# Nvidia Docker: nvidia-smi: command not found Ask Question

Tags: nvidia, docker

I build a `docker` container `FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04` in my Dockerfile to have the `CUDA Toolkit` installed.

My architecture is the one depicted in the official [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) repo

[image: nvidia-docker layers]

After the build and run I get

```
$ nvidia-smi
bash: nvidia-smi: command not found
```

I have a `DOCKER_HOST` that points to the running Docker Nvidia container (the GPUs machine) like

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://x.x.x.x:2376
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set NVIDIA_VER=367.57
```

and the I connect to the docker instance binding the ports when doing the tunnel to the machine:

```
$ ssh -i "$DOCKER_CERT" docker@$IP -g -R 10250:localhost:10250 -L 0.0.0.0:3000:127.0.0.1:3000  -L 0.0.0.0:8181:127.0.0.1:8181 -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 -L 4567:127.0.0.1:4567
```

My docker instance is started as usual

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name $CONTAINER_NAME -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_IMG:$CONTAINER_VERSION $CMD
```

I can connect to the docker nvidia instance from the docker host:

```
loreto@nvidia-docker:~$ sudo nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
Fri Mar 17 09:08:03 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           Off  | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   35C    P8    17W / 125W |      0MiB /  4036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and even

```
loreto@nvidia-docker:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Mar 17 09:12:59 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           Off  | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   35C    P8    17W / 125W |      0MiB /  4036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
```

while from my container `$CONTAINER_NAME` when running I cannot see it

```
$ docker exec -it $CONTAINER_NAME bash
$ nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi: command not found
```

The  `$CONTAINER_NAME` was built `FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04`

I have asked this question as issue to nvidia-docker github repo [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/341).

[UPDATE]
I have solved the issue, attaching the devices and setting the driver on the container when running it like:

```
docker run --rm -it --device=/dev/nvidiactl --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm --device=/dev/nvidia0 -v nvidia_driver_367.57:/usr/local/nvidia:ro --name $CONTAINER_NAME -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_IMG:$CONTAINER_VERSION $CMD
```

Of course the `DOCKER_HOST` must be set and the tunnel must be open.

Comment: I think you may be confused about the usage of `docker` vs. `nvidia-docker`. If you want the benefits of nvidia docker, you need to start the container with `nvidia-docker`. The reason for this is discussed [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Why%20NVIDIA%20Docker): "The required character devices and driver files are mounted when starting the container on the target machine" If you start the container with `docker`, that won't happen. So to demonstrate running `nvidia-smi` from within the container, I suggest `sudo nvidia-docker run --rm -ti nvidia/cuda bash` then `nvidia-smi`

Comment: @RobertCrovella uhm things are becoming clear...in the meanwhile I try to build the container, is this the same of running my container passing the nvidia device/volume i.e. like `docker run -it --device=/dev/nvidiactl --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm --device=/dev/nvidia0 --volume-driver nvidia-docker -v nvidia_driver_367.57:/usr/local/nvidia:ro --name $CONTAINER_NAME -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_IMG:$CONTAINER_VERSION bash`?

Comment: I think it's unlikely we're going to sort this out in the comments.  My suggestion would be to get familiar with `nvidia-docker` by following the tutorial [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/nvidia-docker-gpu-server-application-deployment-made-easy/).  There is a particular point in that tutorial where you start a bash shell in the container.  If you want to demonstrate `nvidia-smi`, just run it at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `nvidia-docker` over normal `docker` installed version.

Command is:

> curl https://get.docker.com | sh 
> && sudo systemctl --now enable docker

Then

> distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) 
> && curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg 
> && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | 
> sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | 
> sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list

Then

> sudo apt-get update

Then

> sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2

Now once you have installed `nvidia-docker2` - First check the groups your user id is part of using the groups command

> groups

If you don't see `docker` as a listed group then run this command first

> sudo groupadd docker

> sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

Now you need to log out and log back again (if this is not possible due to a remote ssh server - then open a new terminal with ssh to same server).

Run

> sudo systemctl restart docker

Now check the `groups` again. You should see your user id having the `docker` group. If this is not the case - fix this first. Then run:

> sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi

You should have `nvidia-smi` running now within a `docker`

Select the appropriate docker version with the right nvidia-driver version and version of ubuntu to use for your application from this link - https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags